# Jquery auto numbering based on class div, but reset counter on specified div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I have a problem with this JQUERY numbering, all I want just reset counter of green tables data, first tables data is good 1),2),3) but next tables data is 4),5),6) I want to reset it to 1),2),3),4) and so on for the green tables data

The code I used in javascript is

```
            var num1=1,num2=1,num3=1,num4=1;
            $(".lv0name").each( function() {$(this).text(romanize(num1)  +". "+ $(this).text());num1++;});
            $(".lv1name").each( function() {$(this).text(num2 +". "+ $(this).text());num2++;});
            $(".lv2name").each( function() {$(this).text(num3 +"). "+ $(this).text());num3++;});
            $(".lv3name").each( function() {$(this).text(num4 +". "+ $(this).text());num4++;});
```

Part of the code is

```
<table border="1" id="tabletabular" class="tablenum">
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="blue" class="lv0name" id="root40" style="padding-left: 20px;">Luas Wilayah</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="yellow" class="lv1name" style="padding-left: 40px;">Daratan</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="yellow" class="lv1name" style="padding-left: 40px;">Laut 12 Mil dari Darat</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="yellow" class="lv1name" style="padding-left: 40px;">Zona Laut</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td bgcolor="green" class="lv2name" style="padding-left: 60px;">Laut Teritorial</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="green" class="lv2name" style="padding-left: 60px;">Zona Ekonomi Ekslusif</td>  
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="green" class="lv2name" style="padding-left: 60px;">Laut Landasan Kontinen</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td bgcolor="yellow" class="lv1name" style="padding-left: 40px;">Panjang Garis Pantai</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="blue" class="lv0name" id="root41" style="padding-left: 20px;">Topografi</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="yellow" class="lv1name" style="padding-left: 40px;">Luas Lahan Berdasarkan Kelas Lereng</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="green" class="lv2name" style="padding-left: 60px;">Datar (0-2 Derajat)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="green" class="lv2name" style="padding-left: 60px;">Bergelombang (2-15 Derajat)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="green" class="lv2name" style="padding-left: 60px;">Curam (15-40 Derajat)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="green" class="lv2name" style="padding-left: 60px;">Sangat Curam (&gt;40 Derajat)</td>
</tr>
```

Here is the screenshot

[image: Table auto numbering with jquery]

Regard

Comment: what about the yellow data 5, should that too resetted

Comment: also in the 3rd segment what should be the number of green rows

Comment: It seems like he's saying if ever a td is immediately preceded with a class of higher (more to the left) level, start over at 1.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using an ordered list?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Sorry I forgot to tell I should reset it too, which Taplar said is correct, if there is new section, it should be reset at 1

Comment: @BillCriswell yes there is a reason I didn't using numbering on php or ordered list

Comment: Mind me asking why? Just thinking about situations you might run into down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you need to iterate over each set and number items till a element of same order or higher is found like

```js
$(".lv0name").each(function(i) {
  $(this).text(romanize(i + 1) + ". " + $(this).text());

  $(this).parent().nextUntil(':has(.lv0name)').find(".lv1name").each(function(i) {
    $(this).text((i + 1) + ". " + $(this).text());

    $(this).parent().nextUntil(':has(.lv1name, .lv0name)').find(".lv2name").each(function(i) {
      $(this).text((i + 1) + ". " + $(this).text());

      $(this).parent().nextUntil(':has(.lv0name, .lv1name, .lv2name)').find(".lv3name").each(function(i) {
        $(this).text((i + 1) + ". " + $(this).text());
      });
    });
  });



});



function romanize(r) {
  return r;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="tabletabular" class="tablenum">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="blue" class="lv0name" id="root40" style="padding-left: 20px;">Luas Wilayah</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="yellow" class="lv1name" style="padding-left: 40px;">Daratan</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="yellow" class="lv1name" style="padding-left: 40px;">Laut 12 Mil dari Darat</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="yellow" class="lv1name" style="padding-left: 40px;">Zona Laut</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="green" class="lv2name" style="padding-left: 60px;">Laut Teritorial</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="green" class="lv2name" style="padding-left: 60px;">Zona Ekonomi Ekslusif</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="green" class="lv2name" style="padding-left: 60px;">Laut Landasan Kontinen</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="yellow" class="lv1name" style="padding-left: 40px;">Panjang Garis Pantai</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="green" class="lv2name" style="padding-left: 60px;">Laut Teritorial</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="green" class="lv2name" style="padding-left: 60px;">Zona Ekonomi Ekslusif</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="blue" class="lv0name" id="root41" style="padding-left: 20px;">Topografi</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="yellow" class="lv1name" style="padding-left: 40px;">Luas Lahan Berdasarkan Kelas Lereng</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="green" class="lv2name" style="padding-left: 60px;">Datar (0-2 Derajat)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="green" class="lv2name" style="padding-left: 60px;">Bergelombang (2-15 Derajat)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="green" class="lv2name" style="padding-left: 60px;">Curam (15-40 Derajat)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="green" class="lv2name" style="padding-left: 60px;">Sangat Curam (&gt;40 Derajat)</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Wow This is what I wanted, I struggling almost 1 day without sleep because of this :D
Thank You Very Much!

Answer (score 1):

Kinda strange, but lets give it a shot...

```js
$(function(){
  var num = 1;
  
  $(".lv0name").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    
    $this.text(num++ +". "+ $this.text());
  });
  
  $(".lv1name").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    
    if ($this.parent().prev().find('td').hasClass('lv0name')) num = 1;
    
    $this.text(num++ +". "+ $this.text());
  });
  
  $(".lv2name").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    
    if ($this.parent().prev().find('td').hasClass('lv1name')) num = 1;
    
    $this.text(num++ +". "+ $this.text());
  });
  
  $(".lv3name").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    
    if ($this.parent().prev().find('td').hasClass('lv2name')) num = 1;
    
    $this.text(num++ +". "+ $this.text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="tabletabular" class="tablenum">
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="blue" class="lv0name" id="root40" style="padding-left: 20px;">Luas Wilayah</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="yellow" class="lv1name" style="padding-left: 40px;">Daratan</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="yellow" class="lv1name" style="padding-left: 40px;">Laut 12 Mil dari Darat</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="yellow" class="lv1name" style="padding-left: 40px;">Zona Laut</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td bgcolor="green" class="lv2name" style="padding-left: 60px;">Laut Teritorial</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="green" class="lv2name" style="padding-left: 60px;">Zona Ekonomi Ekslusif</td>  
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="green" class="lv2name" style="padding-left: 60px;">Laut Landasan Kontinen</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td bgcolor="yellow" class="lv1name" style="padding-left: 40px;">Panjang Garis Pantai</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="blue" class="lv0name" id="root41" style="padding-left: 20px;">Topografi</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="yellow" class="lv1name" style="padding-left: 40px;">Luas Lahan Berdasarkan Kelas Lereng</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="green" class="lv2name" style="padding-left: 60px;">Datar (0-2 Derajat)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="green" class="lv2name" style="padding-left: 60px;">Bergelombang (2-15 Derajat)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="green" class="lv2name" style="padding-left: 60px;">Curam (15-40 Derajat)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="green" class="lv2name" style="padding-left: 60px;">Sangat Curam (&gt;40 Derajat)</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an if condition to your jquery. Change $('.lv2name').each() function as below:

```
 $(".lv2name").each(function() {
 if ($(this).parent().prev().children().attr('class') == 'lv1name') {
   num3 = 1;
 }
 $(this).text(num3 + "). " + $(this).text());
 num3++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here goes a CSS only approach.

There's plenty of benefits to this over the Javascript approach since you can manipulate the DOM and the counters will update automatically. It would be a huge pain to accomplish that with the Javascript approach.

The only special thing you were doing I was able to accomplish with a css `counter`.

```
ol {
  list-style-type: upper-roman;
  list-style-position: inside;
  background-color: blue;
  text-indent: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ol ol {
  list-style-type: decimal;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-indent: 40px
}

ol ol ol {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: green;
  text-indent: 60px
}

ol ol ol li::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section) "). ";
}
```

Here goes a quick demo: https://jsfiddle.net/crswll/ysjrwodL/1/